# Doubt about Duhamel's principle for ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

The following are from pp.26~27, Section 1.5 of *Partial Differential Equations* by Michael E. Taylor.

> Let $A(t)$ be a continuous, $n\times n$ matrix-valued function of $t\in I$. We consider the general linear, homogeneous ODE $$\frac{dy}{dt}=A(t)y,\quad y(0)=y_0.$$ It has a global solution. There is a matrix-valued function $S(s,t)$ such that the unique solution to the equation satisfies $$y(t)=S(t,s)y(s).$$

My question is: Why is $S(t,s)$ continuous in $t,s$? (In the next paragraph the author integrates $S(t,s)$.) I don't know where to start...

Comment: The $k$-th column of $S(t,s)$ equals the value at time $t$ of the solution of the ODE taking value $e_k$ at time $s$, where $e_k$ is the $k$-th vector in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now it suffices to apply the theorem on the continuous dependence of solutions on the initial time.

Comment: @user539887 In fact I'm imagining a slightly more general situation where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is replaced by a Banach space... Does that work in this context?

Comment: If $A(t)$ are **bounded** linear operators depending continuously on $t$ in the norm topology then the result is true (of course, it makes hardly any sense to speak of matrix columns now).  Even when $A(t)$ are infinitesimal generators of some linear semigroups then one can get the result, however proofs become much more complicated.

Comment: @user539887 Thanks for the explanation! Do you have a proof for the Banach case?

Comment: A proof in the Banach space is just the same: the theorem on continuous dependence of solutions on initial value/initial time/parameters carries over, almost word for word, to the case when $A(t)$ is a function into the space of bounded linear operators endowed with the norm topology (*almost* because one has to check if estimates are uniform in initial values belonging to a bounded set). Another approach is the [Peano-Baker series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-transition_matrix#Peano-Baker_series): here it is linear operators that are integrated.